# Maximum size on Json serialized StorageFile in UWP appdata

Tags: c#, json, uwp, storagefile

I am trying to save a file to the local appdata in a UWP app using Json.
The code creates a file in the folder and then writes the data object to it using Json. Here is the code i use:

```
StorageFile file = await localstorage.CreateFileAsync("filename.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)    
var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
var writer = new StreamWriter(filestream);
var jsonwriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
serializer.Serialize(jsonwriter, DataObject);
```

Immediately this seems to work and the file seems to be saved successfully, however opening the file manually reveals that it is exactly 16KB and stopped in the middle of an object.

I have been unable to find any mention of a size limitation on any of these objects (streams, StorageFile, Json serializer etc.)

Can anyone explain why the serialization stops at 16KB?

Comment: writer.Flush() comes to mind, but I'm not so sure now.

Comment: Also try to dispose filestream, writer and so on. The best - use `using`statement.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `using` statement as Romasz suggested and thereby disposing the filestream, writer etc. seems to have fixed my issue.

New code:

```
StorageFile file = await createFile("filename.json");
using (JsonTextWriter jsonwriter =new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
    serializer.Serialize(jsonwriter, DataObject);
}
```

Thank you for your answer.